# Where can I get U.S. size 15B SPD clipless shoes?

Tags: shimano, shoes, clipless

I want to get some large clipless shoes for an indoor stationary cycle at my gym, which I presume uses SPD. I wear a U.S. size 15B and it is difficult to find shoes that long, let alone with a narrow width? Shoes I could source in Toronto, Canada, would be best, but I can get them in the U.S. if I must.

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.softmoc.com/ca/shoesize.asp), that would be a size 50 in European, which is what most cycling shows are sized in.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily make that presumption, as SPD pedals are only one of three clipless styles in common use. But as regards your general question, I would have thought you'd get more joy on Google than on SE. Have you even tried this?

Comment: I have spent literally hours searching both today and on previous occasions (when I gave up after not finding anything). I have tried several search terms and looked on several manufacturers' and retailers' web sites and looked at individual shoes. The manufacturers don't always make it easy to find which of their shoes are available in particular sizes either. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman then I have my fingers crossed that SE has some users in Toronto who might be able to help you, good luck.

Comment: Go to your LBS and ask for them? It'll likely be a special order, but chain reaction cycles among other places do sell some shoes in EUR 50 in standard width. I find cycling shoes to run narrow to begin with, so a non-wide 50 might be OK.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain…

One place that I've found that seems to stock large shoes is [Bike Tires Direct](http://biketiresdirect.com). Both Shimano and Sidi seem to make models that go up to at least size 52. If you don't want to order from the US, you could still use their listings to find some candidates and then ask your LBS what they can order for you.

The shoes will come in two styles "road" and "mountain." Road shoes have a flat sole that the cleat mounts onto (and thus are quite unpleasant to walk in). Mountain shoes have a recess for the clear. Road shoes often use different cleats than mountain shoes (three-bolt vs two-bolt). Cleats usually come with pedals, not with the shoes. You can also buy cleats separately.

So find out what kind of cleats your bike needs and then get shoes & cleats to match.